# Addressing splint warnings about functions "not used" while they are passed as parameters

Tags: c, splint

On a program of me, the [splint](http://www.splint.org/) checker warns:

```
expat-test.c:23:1: Function exported but not used outside expat-test: start
  A declaration is exported, but not used outside this module. Declaration can
  use static qualifier. (Use -exportlocal to inhibit warning)
   expat-test.c:38:1: Definition of start
```

The start() function **is** used. The program uses the [expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) XML parser which works with callbacks. You give the parser a function:

```
XML_SetElementHandler(parser, start, end);
```

and the parser calls it back at some points. This is a very common idiom in C and I wonder why splint complains. I find nothing in the [FAQ](http://www.splint.org/faq.html) or in the [manual](http://www.splint.org/manual/html/sec8.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you call `XML_SetElementHandler()` in the same translation unit (normally the .c source file) in which `start()` is defined? If so, the warning might be correct: Add `static` to the function definition and check if your application still links without errors.

Comment: Thanks, the start() function was indeed in the same file and adding "static" solved the problem. splint is now happy and the application still works.

Comment: And I just noticed that splint's warning message gives a hint about "static". Shame on me.

Answer (score 2):

The 'static' keyword effectively hides the name of a function from other translation units (.C file, usually). The code's still there, and from that C file you can get the address of the function (but not from other C files). You can then pass the address to other translation units, either by calling functions, or returning the address from a function, or by storing it in a global variable, etc.

Comment: You should clarify that you can only get the address of the (static) function in the source file that it is defined in; there is nothing to stop you passing the address of that function to code outside the source file it is defined in.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to declare all functions which are not being exported as static. I have been taught and currently believe that it is good practice to do so. (Disclaimer: As with most things, there are numerous exceptions to this 'rule'.)